# Regex - Looking for a number either at the BOL or EOL but also not embed in other numbers or text

Tags: regex

I want to find '106'. But it can't be in a longer number like 21067 nor can it be in a text string like y106M. But I also want to find it if it is at the beginning, or the end of line, or if it is the line.

So these lines are out:

> ```
> 106M
> 1106
> 106in a string is bad even if it starts the line
> And it may finish with the target but not as the tail of a string106
> ```

but these are in:

> ```
> 106 something else
> another 106
> And of couse "106' will work as well
> I just want 106 to show up but not embedded in other numbers or text
> but it's OK is the end of the line is 106
> 106 may also start the line
> ```

I have tried the following search string and many variations of it:

> (^|[^0-9A-Za-z])106($|[^0-9A-Za-z])

I'm new-ish to regex, and I likely don't have a handle on how the anchor characters work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `\b` word boundary assertion:

```
\b106\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7ptBHG/1/)

Or be more specific with [lookarounds](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html):

```
(?<=^|\W)106(?=$|\W)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/z4CiFt/1/)

or, as pointed out in comments, `(?<!\w)106(?!\w)` works too. Or `(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9])106(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9])` will work even better since `_` is included in `\w` and `\W` set of characters.

Comment: Thank you. Do you also know a good resource for regex 'how-to' ?

Comment: I linked to one of them -- [rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com)  [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) is another. Best of luck!